# Splitting strings to lists using Python

Tags: python, string, list, split

I've got this string:

```
string = '26.10-8-00 - Fabricação de componentes eletrônicos | 46.51-6-01 - Comércio atacadista de equipamentos de informática | 95.11-8-00 - Reparação e manutenção de computadores e de equipamentos periféricos'
```

I want to create a list with those codes out of it. It might look like this:

```
mylist = ['26.10-8-00', '46.51-6-01', '95.11-8-00']
```

Comment: using regular exression? `re.findall(r'[0-9]+.[0-9]+-[0-9]-[0-9]+', string)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

using [re.findall](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.findall)

```
import re
string = '26.10-8-00 - Fabricação de componentes eletrônicos | 46.51-6-01 - Comércio atacadista de equipamentos de informática | 95.11-8-00 - Reparação e manutenção de computadores e de equipamentos periféricos'
output = re.findall(r'\d+\.\d+-\d+-\d+', string)
# ['26.10-8-00', '46.51-6-01', '95.11-8-00']
```

Answer (score 1):

I'd split the string by `|` to get a list, and then split each value by `-` and extract just the date part of it:

```
result = [x.split(' - ')[0] for x in s.split(' | ')]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use regular expressions:

```
import re
string = '26.10-8-00 - Fabricação de componentes eletrônicos | 46.51-6-01 - Comércio atacadista de equipamentos de informática | 95.11-8-00 - Reparação e manutenção de computadores e de equipamentos periféricos'
new_string = [i for i in re.split("\s-\s|(?<=\|)\s(?=\d)", string) if re.findall("^\d+\.\d+-\d+-\d+", i)]
```

Output:

```
['26.10-8-00', '46.51-6-01', '95.11-8-00']
```

Answer (score 1):

Mines a more simple approach but gets the job done.

```
string = '26.10-8-00 - Fabricação de componentes eletrônicos | 46.51-6-01 - Comércio atacadista de equipamentos de informática | 95.11-8-00 - Reparação e manutenção de computadores e de equipamentos periféricos'
mylist = []
for x in string.split(" | "):
  mylist.append(x.split(" - ")[0])
print(mylist)
```

Output

```
['26.10-8-00', '46.51-6-01', '95.11-8-00']
```

Comment: Consider `.strip()` to remove the leading space in the last two results.

Comment: i fixed it by adding spaces infront and behind the | in "for x in string.split(" | "):"